# how to retrieve data from two tables that is passed as a dictionary

Tags: python, ajax, qsqlquery

This is js file:

```
let objectname = $('#object-name option:selected').text();
let objectname2 = $('#object-name2 option:selected').text();
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: `/views/generatecolumns/$data`,
    data : {
        obj1 : objectname,
        obj2 : objectname2
    },
    dataType: 'json',
})
```

This is route:

```
@app.route('/views/generatecolumns/<objname>>',methods=['GET'])
def get_obj_details(objname):
    data=bo.getobjdata(objname)
    return data
```

What changes can be do to below code to retrieve data

```
def getobjdata(objname):
    exec_cmd='select * from [obj].' + objname 
    try:
        result=db.retreive_columns_query(exec_cmd)
    except Exception as e:
        result = []
    finally:    
        return {"columns":result,'message':'success'}
```

how can I change this code?